# "Java Heap Space:OutOfMemoryError" while running a MapReduce Program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I had given an entire folder as input to the MR job.

I have used CombineFileBinaryInputFormat ( extends CombineFileInputFormat )as the input format to my MR job. I have used "setMaxSplitSize(262144000)" this method in my CombineFileBinaryInputFormat constructor,since my block size is 250MB. The split for the files happen by packet, should i put a check somewhere to test if the limit has exceeded 250MB or is it implicit. The complete code is available at [here](https://github.com/divyagangigunta123/MRPcapParser).

But I'm  facing the "Java Heap Space" error while running a MapReduce program.

Below is the part of code for reference:

```
public class CombineBinaryInputFormat extends CombineFileInputFormat<KeyWritable, ValueWritable>{

     public CombineBinaryInputFormat(){
        super();
        setMaxSplitSize(262144000); 
        }

My StackTrace:
==============
    15/05/05 11:52:47 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 318
    15/05/05 11:52:47 INFO input.CombineFileInputFormat: DEBUG: Terminated node allocation with : CompletedNodes: 1, size left: 52027734
    15/05/05 11:52:47 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
    15/05/05 11:52:47 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local634564612_0001
    15/05/05 11:52:47 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/raghuveer634564612/.staging/job_local634564612_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
    15/05/05 11:52:47 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/raghuveer634564612/.staging/job_local634564612_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.
end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
    15/05/05 11:52:48 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/var/hadoop/mapreduce/localRunner/raghuveer/job_local634564612_0001/job_local634564612_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
    15/05/05 11:52:48 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/var/hadoop/mapreduce/localRunner/raghuveer/job_local634564612_0001/job_local634564612_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
    15/05/05 11:52:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
    15/05/05 11:52:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local634564612_0001
    15/05/05 11:52:48 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
    15/05/05 11:52:48 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
    15/05/05 11:52:48 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
    15/05/05 11:52:48 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local634564612_0001_m_000000_0
    15/05/05 11:52:48 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
    15/05/05 11:52:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: Paths:/user/usr/local/upload/20120713T07-45-42.682358000Z_79.150.138.86-1412.c2s_ndttrace:0+78550,/user/usr/local/upload/20120713T07-45-43.356723000Z_151.40.240.66-53426.c2s_ndttrace:0+32768,/user/usr/local/upload/20120713T07-45-43.718556000Z_85.26.235.102-25300.c2s_ndttrace:0+10130,/user/usr/local/upload
         .....
         .....
         .....
/20120713T08-33-41.259331000Z_84.122.129.103-61321.c2s_ndttrace:0+19148,/user/usr/local/upload/20120713T08-33-54.972649000Z_86.69.144.214-49599.c2s_ndttrace:0+63014,/user/usr/local/upload/20120713T08-33-56.162340000Z_41.143.91.156-50785.c2s_ndttrace:0+13658,/user/usr/local/upload/20120713T08-33-59.768261000Z_31.187.12.141-50274.c2s_ndttrace:0+126542,/user/usr/local/upload/20120713T08-34-03.950055000Z_78.119.172.109-51495.c2s_ndttrace:0+92676,/user/usr/local/upload/20120713T08-34-08.378534000Z_87.7.113.115-62238.c2s_ndttrace:0+49410,/user/usr/local/upload/20120713T08-34-26.258570000Z_151.13.227.66-33198.c2s_ndttrace:0+2666092
    15/05/05 11:52:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local634564612_0001 running in uber mode : false
    15/05/05 11:52:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    15/05/05 11:52:50 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
    15/05/05 11:52:53 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 78643196(314572784)
    15/05/05 11:52:53 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 300
    15/05/05 11:52:53 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 251658240
    15/05/05 11:52:53 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 314572800
    15/05/05 11:52:53 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 78643196; length = 19660800
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (82) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (82) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:54 WARN pcap.PcapReader: Payload start (74) is larger than packet data (68). Returning empty payload.
    15/05/05 11:52:55 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
    15/05/05 11:52:55 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
    15/05/05 11:52:55 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 105296; bufvoid = 314572800
    15/05/05 11:52:55 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 78643196(314572784); kvend = 78637988(314551952); length = 5209/19660800
    15/05/05 11:52:55 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
    15/05/05 11:52:55 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
    15/05/05 11:52:55 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
    15/05/05 11:52:55 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local634564612_0001
    java.lang.Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at net.ripe.hadoop.pcap.PcapReader.nextPacket(PcapReader.java:208)
        at net.ripe.hadoop.pcap.PcapReader.access$0(PcapReader.java:173)
        at net.ripe.hadoop.pcap.PcapReader$PacketIterator.fetchNext(PcapReader.java:554)
        at net.ripe.hadoop.pcap.PcapReader$PacketIterator.hasNext(PcapReader.java:559)
        at net.ripe.hadoop.pcap.io.reader.PcapRecordReader.nextKeyValue(PcapRecordReader.java:57)
        at net.ripe.hadoop.pcap.io.reader.CombineBinaryRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineBinaryRecordReader.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:69)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    15/05/05 11:52:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local634564612_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
    15/05/05 11:52:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 25
        File System Counters
            FILE: Number of bytes read=29002348
            FILE: Number of bytes written=29450636
            FILE: Number of read operations=0
            FILE: Number of large read operations=0
            FILE: Number of write operations=0
            HDFS: Number of bytes read=103142
            HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
            HDFS: Number of read operations=6
            HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
            HDFS: Number of write operations=1
        Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=1303
            Map output records=1303
            Map output bytes=105296
            Map output materialized bytes=0
            Input split bytes=38078
            Combine input records=0
            Spilled Records=0
            Failed Shuffles=0
            Merged Map outputs=0
            GC time elapsed (ms)=593
            CPU time spent (ms)=0
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=1745092608
        File Input Format Counters 
            Bytes Read=0
```

Here,I'm sending hundreds of files as input to the MapReduce job and I'm using default block size i.e,64MB and my RAM size is 4GB and I'm using hadoop on 32 bit system.Now,I'm facing Java heap space error.Is there any solution to overcome this issue,if I give hundreds of files as input to the MR job with 64MB as the block size and by using CombineFileInputFormat and with RAM 4GB.

please suggest me on this issue ...

Comment: How many files and how many blocks?

Comment: No of files:318 ,Noblocks:1(defaultblocksize:64MB), Hadoop is running on 32 bit system

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as logic goes ... split size will never lead to Java Heap Space error .

It has to do something with ur code logic like , for a given key aggregating too much data in memory .

Can u please provide the stackTrace for further analysis

Comment: `split size will never lead to Java Heap Space error ` I beg to differ, `CombineFileInputFormat` is usually the number one reason to run out of memory- depending on how many files are input to the job.

Comment: it has nothing to do with combine file input format , as fileinput format just chooses how to split and how to read records  (Record reader) . Providing stack trace will confirm this ,

Comment: `CombineFileInputFormat` batches files, hence the name. Batching files together takes quite a good amount of RAM depending on how many files need to be combined.